# How to create a bookmarklet to change maxlength of an input box

Tags: javascript, dom, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I've got this
[image]
and want to change the maxlength value to, lets say, 2000 with a simple click of a bookmarklet, yet I'm clueless how JS works, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

I've scoured google for something similar, but I don't seem to be able to find anything that I can apply to my case. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the corresponding element using something like [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and then use setAttribute:

```
var el = document.querySelector(".textareaHolder textarea");
el.setAttribute('maxLength',2000);
```